# Proper way to inherit a class template from a base class while specializing the template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17, template-specialization

I'm in the process of designing a virtual processor and I want to represent different size registers that the virtual cpu will use. I also would like to contain them into a single container regardless of their actual sizes and or types.

I would have a structure that looks like this to store the Registers

```
struct Memory {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Register>> bank;
};
```

I'm trying to create a base empty class as such:

```
struct Register {};
```

Now I will be inheriting from this base class to create my different types of supported registers. These registers also depend on a few typedefs...

```
typedef std::int8_t   i8;
typedef std::int16_t i16;
typedef std::int32_t i32;
typedef std::int64_t i64;

typedef std::uint8_t   u8;
typedef std::uint16_t u16;
typedef std::uint32_t u32;
typedef std::uint64_t u64;

const u16 BYTE = 0x08, WORD = 0x10, DWORD = 0x20, QWORD = 0x40;
```

Lets say I want to have a Register that its underlying data type is a u8, another a u16 and so on...

```
struct Register8 : Register {
    u8 value;
    u8 getValue() const { return value; }
};

struct Register16 : Register {
    u16 value;
    u8 getValue() const { return value; }
};

struct Register32 : Register {
    u32 value;
    u32 getValue() const { return value; }
};

struct Register64 : Register {
    u64 value;
    u64 getValue() const { return value; }
};
```

So this is simple enough however I don't like the fact that I'm naming each of my register classes differently and I'm seeing some duplicate code other than the difference in types so we should be able to create a template...

```
struct Register{};

template<typename T>
Register_t : Register {
    T value;
    T getValue() const { return value; }
};
```

This is easy enough; However I would like to specialize this class:

```
struct Register {};

template<typename T>
struct Register_t : Register {
    T value;
    T getValue() const { return value; }
};

template<>
struct Register_t<u8> {
    u8 value;
    u8 getValue() const { return value; }
};

template<>
struct Register_t<u16> {
    u16 value;
    u16 getValue() const { return value; }
};  

template<>
struct Register_t<u32> {
    u16 value;
    u16 getValue() const { return value; }
};

template<>
struct Register_t<u64> {
    u16 value;
    u16 getValue() const { return value; }
};
```

Okay this goes back on what I said earlier about duplicate code and we are introducing more, however in my situation these will be the only acceptable types ever so this bit of duplication is not an issue.

Everything so far is so good...

Now let's say I try to use this...

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Register.h"

int main () {
    Register_t<u8> r8;
    r8.value = 8;
    Register_t<u16> r16;
    r16.value = 16;
    Register_t<u32> r32;
    r32.value = 32;
    Register_t<u64> r64; 
    r64.value = 64;

    Memory mem;
    mem.bank.push_back( std::make_shared<Register>( r8 ) );
    mem.bank.push_back( std::make_shared<Register>( r16 ) );
    mem.bank.push_back( std::make_shared<Register>( r32 ) );
    mem.bank.push_back( std::make_shared<Register>( r64 ) );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

Okay so I successfully stored these as shared pointers into a vector. Now comes the problem or issue... Let's try to access these values from the class

```
int main () {
    // ....

    for ( auto& b : mem.bank ) {
        std::cout << b->getValue() << '\n'; // Uh oh class Register has no member getValue() ...
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So here is my problem; I'm not sure how to indirectly call the inherited class's `getValue()` function or how to properly inherit this type of design structure - class hierarchy. Or if I should eliminate specialization altogether... This is where I'm stuck and any and all help would be appreciative.

Comment: The trouble is, the compiler needs to know the specific type to do things like `std::cout << v`. But maybe `std::variant` and `std::visit` would be helpful for this...

Comment: @aschepler I was thinking about them but I was trying to keep this as simple as possible with the least amount of overhead while also trying to keep it generic and portable. Also I'm not familiar with variant and visit yet... but could be good practice or a good exercise...

Comment: @aschepler I could of not worried about a single container and had corresponding containers one for each type of specialization but I didn't want to have to manage 4 containers.

Comment: *"This is easy enough; However I would like to specialize this class:"* your specializations are mostly as base case (you forget inheritance though), so unneeded.

Comment: `struct Register{ virtual ~Register() = default; virtual void print() const = 0; };` or `using Register = std::variant<Register_t<u8>, Register_t<u16>, Register_t<u32>, Register_t<u64>>` (and drop inheritance).